# Strange behavior with SQLItes onConfigure method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to implement a foreign key in my database table, for that I need to call onConfigure where I set the PRAGMA. However implementation of this method gives me strange behavior. **When I use the @Override annotation the eclipse intellisense asks me to remove it** , and when I remove it I get a different set of warnings **This method is not overriding anything with the current build target, but will in API level 16 (current target is 11)**

Following is my code snippet for the particular problem code:

```
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE0);
        db.execSQL(unique); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println("Hello from on Configure"); 
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");

    }


}
```

This is my Manifest SDK Declaration:

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: Does not work, however if I add @SuppressLint("Override") before the method declaration it works.

Comment: In which method you are getting @Override error ? Have you write the methods on your own or used intellisense ?

Comment: All others are written by intellisense albeit for this method, the problem code is attached with the question.

Comment: The @Overriden error are you getting for `onConfigure` method ?

Comment: Yes Madam, its explained in the problem code! As far as I can guess its because of the SDK version thing.

Answer (score 2):

To stop android lint from raising an error, annotate the `onConfigure`
override in `DatabaseOpenHelper` to be **JellyBean or higher**. Older
android versions will continue to use the old mechanism already checked
for in the onOpen override.

You need to add the `@TargetAPI` in your class as below:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
      @Override
      public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          super.onConfigure(db); }
```

Check out the [Reference](https://github.com/mitmel/SimpleContentProvider/pull/23)

Comment: What happens when the target API is lower? It will still throw that warning? Or will the compiler skip it for older versions? That way my foreign key constraint fails.

Comment: It may be because of you may be using the JAVA 5 compiler. This is most likely because you are switching between Java 1.5 and Java 1.6. In 1.5 you couldn't mark interface implementations with @Override, but you can in 1.6.